# Slick, UUID and Postgres

Tags: scala, uuid, slick

I'm trying to map a `java.util.UUID` to a Slick column, which should be possible according to this: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/79

I'm defining the columns as follows:

```
def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.DBType("UUID"))
```

According to the Github issue linked above the manual DBType override should not be necessary but I couldn't get it to work without.

The error I'm getting when I'm trying to insert a row into Postgres is this:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea
```

Seems that the mapping from `java.util.UUID` to a Postgres `uuid` type doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the following artifact versions:

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.1",
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1101-jdbc41"
```

My postgres version is
    $ psql --version
    psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try `def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. If I do that, Slick tries to set the Postgres type (during DDL generation) to `OTHER`.

Comment: Note that when you check PostgreSQL server version, you should query your database with `SELECT version();`. `$ psql --version` returns psql (client application) version. Those two can differ.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug. Please report one https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/new and refer to: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/79 or simply re-open the latter.

**UPDATE**: Not a bug, but you imported the wrong driver. This happens often enough to people. Slick should catch that and provide a better error message. Here's the ticket: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/670